# Does a cell contains a CheckBox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two types of checkboxes.

Each type of checkbox is defined in its' column :

- the first ones are named `"CheckBoxeMacro"&i` (in **column 3**), and
- the second ones are named `"CheckBox"&i` in (**column 5**).

I want the second type of checkboxes describing my instruction about a sum, as long as the data to add are set in rows between two cells where my first type of checkboxes (`"checkboxMacro"&i`) are.

I tried this but it seems that "`TypeOf`" is wrongly used.

How can I stop to the correct row using the fact we have to stop when the cell contains a checkbox and not a number or Nothing?

```
Sub SommerTest()
    Dim i As Byte
    For r = 1 To 178
        If TypeOf Sheets(2).Cells(r, 3) Is Object  Then
            For i = r + 1 To 178
                While IsNumeric(Sheets(2).Cells(i, 3)) _
                            And (Sheets(2).Cells(i, 3).Value <> "")
                    With Sheets(2)
                    If .OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = True _
                           And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 4)="" Then
                        For Each j In Array(7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17)
                           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(r, j).Value = _
                             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(r, j).Value _
                             +(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, j).Value) _
                             *(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 3).Value)
                            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value _
                                    = "Sélectionné"
                        Next j
                      ElseIf .OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = False _
                                And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 4) _
                                        = "Sélectionné" Then
                          For Each j In Array(7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17)
                            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(r, j).Value = _
                              ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(r, j).Value _
                              -(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, j).Value) _
                              *(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 3).Value)
                            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value = ""
                          Next j
                      End If
                    End With
                Wend
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Cells don't contain shapes. You have to loop through the checkboxes and test the `TopLeftCell` property to determine where they are.

Comment: Yes I have tried this before : Sub SommerTest()

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim h As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    For l = 1 To 178
        r = l + 1
        h = (Sheets(2).Shapes("CheckBoxMacro" & l).Top) / (Sheets(2).Shapes("CheckBoxMacro" & l).Width) + 1
        k = (Sheets(2).Shapes("CheckBoxMacro" & r).Top) / (Sheets(2).Shapes("CheckBoxMacro" & r).Width) - 1
    
            For i = h To k
...

Comment: it make a huge difference in understanding code when it's indented (especially with heavily-nested code).

Answer (score 3):

As @Rory says, You could investigate around the `topleftcell` property, not sure on it's accuracy in relation to the size of the control, but something like

`.shapes("CheckBox21").oleformat.object.topleftcell.address`

`.oleobjects("CheckBox21").topleftcell.address`

```
Dim s as shape

for each s in activesheet.shapes
    if s.oleformat.object.topleftcell.address=activecell.address.......

    end if
next s
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, what is active cell exactly?

Comment: Something that should very rarely be used

Comment: Basicly I want to describe the row of the cell containing the checkbox to stop my instruction there. Why cant we ask if a cell contains a checkbox whereas we can tell if a cell contains numeric data or if the cell is empty? There must be a Trace of the checkbox somehow in the cell... Especially since it's an Object and we can do it with the object image. Where Am I wrong?